# Is daemon-reload called when the Unit is enabled with systemctl enable?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Question is:
When I call **systemctl enable** [Unit File Name], system manager configuration is reloaded. I wonder whether systemd is doing this stuff with **daemon-reloa**d or not in the background. According to reference link that I put below tells "system manager is reloaded in a way equivalent to daemon-reload).

Reference:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html
enable UNIT…, enable PATH…
Enable one or more units or unit instances. This will create a set of symlinks, as encoded in the "[Install]" sections of the indicated unit files. **After the symlinks have been created, the system manager configuration is reloaded (in a way equivalent to daemon-reload)**, in order to ensure the changes are taken into account immediately.

/Br
Cadoe

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Unless you specify the `--no-reload` when calling `systemctl enable/disable/reenable/mask/unmask/revert/link`, systemd is reloaded the same way as if you'd call `systemctl daemon-reload`.

There are certain exceptions when the daemon is NOT reloaded, like when executing `systemctl` in a chroot, using the `--root` option, working on a global scope (`--global`), etc.

Relevant [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) snippets:

> enable UNIT…, enable PATH…
>
> Depending on whether --system, --user, --runtime, or --global is specified, this enables the unit for the system, for the calling user only, for only this boot of the system, or for all future logins of all users. Note that **in the last case, no systemd daemon configuration is reloaded**.
>
> --root=
>
> When used with enable/disable/is-enabled (and related commands), use the specified root path when looking for unit files. If this option is present, **systemctl will operate on the file system directly, instead of communicating with the systemd daemon to carry out changes**.